# H2O Random Forest Hangs on Completion

Tags: r, h2o

I'm training a Random Forest using h2o and R on a large (~6 million) row dataset and ~50 output levels. Despite the progress bar hitting 100% the console (and the processor!) is still busy and hangs for over an hour (so far!). Definitely not resource limitations, I have 120gb of RAM and a couple of dozen cores.

Hard to give a fully reproducible example given the nature of the issue but there are 35 variables, half of which are factors, I'm running the model training through R with the following options:

```
rforest <- h2o.randomForest(y = y.var
                          , x = x.vars
                          , training_frame = trainData.h2o
                          , validation_frame = testData.h2o
                          , ntrees = 100
                          , stopping_rounds = 3
                          , seed = 42
                          , model_id = modCode
                          , mtries = -1)
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue/has an explanation/knows a workaround, please?

Comment: How many levels are in your factors?  Are there any that have hundreds or thousands of levels?  Did you start the H2O cluster with enough RAM?  It defaults to 4GB unless you specify something bigger.

Comment: Only one is above a dozen, that's at a couple of hundred. H2O server has 100GB allocated when it's booted.

Comment: The next steps to try here are:  Using Flow, look at Admin->View Logs for anything suspicious.  Look at Admin->Profiler and Admin->Stack Trace to see what is happening.

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but I've found the GridSearch progress bar to be pretty inaccurate if you don't specify a max_run_time parameter - it seems to move in a logarithmic fashion - if I were to give progress updates every 5 minutes, it would look something like 50%, 75%, 90%, 95%, 96%, 97%, 97%, 97%.....

Answer (score 0):

Did you do logarithmic transformation of response variable (i.e. `y`) before running the model? If yes, then are you sure you did not have any `y = 1` values BEFORE you log-transformed it? I had a similar issue, and model worked really fast after I removed from data set the rows with `y = 1`.